# Can't get C# default interface method to compile

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, default-interface-member

C# 8.0 has a new feature that lets you [add a default implementation to a method on an interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#default-interface-methods). Either I'm doing something wrong or this feature doesn't work as advertised. (I'm guessing it's the former.)

I created a new .NET Core 3.1 console app with the following code:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var xxx = new MyClass { MyInt = 5 };
            Console.WriteLine(xxx.GetItNow());
        }
    }

    public interface ITest
    {
        int MyInt { get; set; }
        int GetItNow() => MyInt * 2;
    }

    public class MyClass : ITest
    {
        public int MyInt { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The `Console.WriteLine(xxx.GetItNow()));` statement doesn't compile because

> Myclass does not contain a definition for 'GetItNow()'...

So, the compiler is happy with the fact that `MyClass` doesn't explicitly reference `GetItNow()` (it doesn't complain the `MyClass` doesn't implement the interface). But it doesn't see the default interface member as a public method of the class that implements the interface.

Am I missing something, or is something broken?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine((xxx as ITest).GetItNow()));` default *interface* method belongs to *interface* only (not to *class* which implements it); that's why cast (`xxx as ITest` or alike) is mandatory here. `ITest xxx = new MyClass { MyInt = 5 };` is an alternative (now `xxx` is declared as *interface*)

Comment: Oh! Thank you! Yes, the "documentation" (actually, an overly complex tutorial) contains a mention of the fact that, in order to access the default interface member, you must cast the object reference to the interface. So this compiles: `Console.WriteLine(((ITest)xxx).GetItNow());`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, *interface* default method belongs to the *interface* not to a *class* which implements it; so you have two possibilities:

Cast:

```
  Console.WriteLine(((ITest)xxx).GetItNow()));
```

Declaration change (preferable; `MyClass` is *implementation* detail, often it's a *dependency*; `ITest` - *contract* is the only thing which matter):

```
  ITest xxx = new MyClass { MyInt = 5 };
  // xxx is ITest, so xxx.GetItNow() is legal now 
  Console.WriteLine(xxx.GetItNow());
```

Comment: I would recommend to use the 2nd approach - that one is compile time safe!

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61717913/779967 is excellent and clear answer, I was trying to do the same with this new feature but got stopped by the compiler. Now I know why.

If your intention is to mark some class with an interface and get some functionality attached to it. I’ve been using extension methods on the interface itself to achieve this effect. The only downside is that only functions are supported at this time not properties.

```
public interface ITest
{
    int MyInt { get; set; }
}

public static class ITestExtensions
{
    public static int GetItNow(this ITest self)
    {
        return self.MyInt * 2;
    }
}
```